# Can i compose a posix_time::ptime object my self?

Tags: datetime, posix

I have a object which have a `boost::posix_time::ptime` object in it. And I will get the time from other library which doesnt provide standard time struct, they have their own customized time struct
My problem is that, can I compose a `ptime` object by simply setting those hour/min/sec/millisec variables. Cuz I have tried to do that, It seems that I cant access to them to set value.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#ptime_constr), you can create a ptime object by giving it a date and a time, going down to [fractional seconds](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#time_duration_constr). ptime is immutable once created.